# WebAPI with SQLite via docker-compose in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to get a docker-compose application working on Microsoft Azure.
It consists of 5 containers. One of them is a webapi gateway and the others are the web services that each work with a different SQLite database.
Each container runs an ASP.NET core application with `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim` as the base image.

I have already tried a couple of different approaches, but currently I have an App Service that uses the docker-compose preview feature. Also I try using the shared storage of the App Service for the SQLite databases, but I could also use a storage account with a file share.

The application settings of the App Service are:

```
DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD = **************
DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL = ************
DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME = *************
WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT = 1800
WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE = true
```

No path mappings are set.

**The problem I have is that after a while of waiting for the website to load I get this errror:**

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.
```

The logs under *Deployment Center* show no error, but still log a stopping because of a failed startup:

```
2021_06_21_lw0sdlwk0001K5_docker.log:
2021-06-21T07:54:24.271Z INFO - Starting multi-container app..
2021-06-21T07:54:25.658Z INFO - Pulling image: mycr.azurecr.io/myidentity:latest
2021-06-21T07:54:26.223Z INFO - latest Pulling from myidentity
[...]
2021-06-21T07:54:57.706Z INFO - Digest: sha256:75e2986aff9449726d0adc6527a9580c0f65ba412e0e5e0ce910050490d6e1c6
2021-06-21T07:54:57.715Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycr.azurecr.io/myidentity:latest
2021-06-21T07:54:57.720Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 32 Seconds
2021-06-21T07:54:57.788Z INFO - Starting container for site
2021-06-21T07:54:57.789Z INFO - docker run -d -p 9601:80 --name my-webapi_my-identity_0_01be8dfd -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=my-webapi -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=my-webapi.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=1095d84bf58824c16a572d0860c7fbb5037b53bd0c749ec6c0132ae40aa25479 mycr.azurecr.io/myidentity:latest

2021-06-21T07:54:57.791Z INFO - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2021-06-21T07:55:04.302Z INFO - Pulling image: mycr.azurecr.io/mysensors:latest
2021-06-21T07:55:04.556Z INFO - latest Pulling from mysensors
[...]
2021-06-21T07:55:23.334Z INFO - Digest: sha256:8b9c9f8901ce12e07d63ab14063a759a3cc549ea5b04fa82b6f9c86f502c02a7
2021-06-21T07:55:23.368Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycr.azurecr.io/mysensors:latest
2021-06-21T07:55:23.376Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 19 Seconds
2021-06-21T07:55:23.407Z INFO - Starting container for site
2021-06-21T07:55:23.408Z INFO - docker run -d -p 0:80 --name my-webapi_my-sensors_0_01be8dfd -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=my-webapi -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=my-webapi.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=1095d84bf58824c16a572d0860c7fbb5037b53bd0c749ec6c0132ae40aa25479 mycr.azurecr.io/mysensors:latest

2021-06-21T07:55:23.414Z INFO - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2021-06-21T07:55:23.960Z INFO - Pulling image: mycr.azurecr.io/mymodules:latest
2021-06-21T07:55:24.360Z INFO - latest Pulling from mymodules
[...]
2021-06-21T07:55:32.481Z INFO - Digest: sha256:5701912facfaa69a0035dbfa849d2cb6f228696f23225e18440e0973b2cb59ee
2021-06-21T07:55:32.512Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycr.azurecr.io/mymodules:latest
2021-06-21T07:55:32.515Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 8 Seconds
2021-06-21T07:55:32.540Z INFO - Starting container for site
2021-06-21T07:55:32.542Z INFO - docker run -d -p 0:80 --name my-webapi_my-modules_0_01be8dfd -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=my-webapi -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=my-webapi.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=1095d84bf58824c16a572d0860c7fbb5037b53bd0c749ec6c0132ae40aa25479 mycr.azurecr.io/mymodules:latest

2021-06-21T07:55:32.543Z INFO - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2021-06-21T07:55:33.203Z INFO - Pulling image: mycr.azurecr.io/mysystems:latest
2021-06-21T07:55:33.533Z INFO - latest Pulling from mysystems
[...]
2021-06-21T07:55:35.911Z INFO - Digest: sha256:5e3f2cb43633c9897d7eb3eff16a6ec5e0b3e227f30bdfa44633cfe004fd87d1
2021-06-21T07:55:35.942Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycr.azurecr.io/mysystems:latest
2021-06-21T07:55:35.946Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 2 Seconds
2021-06-21T07:55:35.967Z INFO - Starting container for site
2021-06-21T07:55:35.968Z INFO - docker run -d -p 0:80 --name my-webapi_my-systems_0_01be8dfd -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=my-webapi -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=my-webapi.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=1095d84bf58824c16a572d0860c7fbb5037b53bd0c749ec6c0132ae40aa25479 mycr.azurecr.io/mysystems:latest

2021-06-21T07:55:35.970Z INFO - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2021-06-21T07:55:39.308Z INFO - Pulling image: mycr.azurecr.io/mywebgateway:latest
2021-06-21T07:55:39.510Z INFO - latest Pulling from mywebgateway
[...]
2021-06-21T07:55:40.992Z INFO - Digest: sha256:5e228070c52d254b3b84e137888249fad8cab8b4f2f7d933eb358325de5aaf80
2021-06-21T07:55:41.024Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for mycr.azurecr.io/mywebgateway:latest
2021-06-21T07:55:41.028Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 1 Seconds
2021-06-21T07:55:41.041Z INFO - Starting container for site
2021-06-21T07:55:41.042Z INFO - docker run -d -p 0:5000 --name my-webapi_mywebgateway_0_01be8dfd -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=my-webapi -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=my-webapi.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=1095d84bf58824c16a572d0860c7fbb5037b53bd0c749ec6c0132ae40aa25479 mycr.azurecr.io/mywebgateway:latest

2021-06-21T07:55:41.044Z INFO - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2021-06-21T08:25:43.599Z ERROR - multi-container unit was not started successfully
2021-06-21T08:25:43.611Z INFO - Container logs from my-webapi_my-identity_0_01be8dfd = 2021-06-21T07:56:16.676618761Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
2021-06-21T07:56:16.707243987Z Storing keys in a directory '/root/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
2021-06-21T07:56:17.290910713Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
2021-06-21T07:56:17.290965213Z No XML encryptor configured. Key {5107e3da-acf1-499b-9989-f843a30ac1ce} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
2021-06-21T07:56:18.347418546Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:18.347471946Z Starting IdentityServer4 version 4.1.1+cebd52f5bc61bdefc262fd20739d4d087c6f961f
2021-06-21T07:56:18.451447568Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:18.452070777Z You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.
2021-06-21T07:56:18.527667511Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:18.527718411Z Using the default authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer
2021-06-21T07:56:19.579462995Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:19.579509596Z Now listening on: http://[::]:5100
2021-06-21T07:56:19.586114086Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:19.586131586Z Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2021-06-21T07:56:19.586136087Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:19.586139887Z Hosting environment: Development
2021-06-21T07:56:19.586143387Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:19.586148587Z Content root path: /app

2021-06-21T08:25:47.720Z INFO - Container logs from my-webapi_my-sensors_0_01be8dfd = 2021-06-21T07:56:12.018250361Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
2021-06-21T07:56:12.029143948Z Storing keys in a directory '/root/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
2021-06-21T07:56:12.629404862Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
2021-06-21T07:56:12.629459563Z No XML encryptor configured. Key {57a498a5-3dac-421d-9fe0-7f8da08116f4} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
2021-06-21T07:56:17.460686476Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:17.460744377Z Now listening on: http://[::]:5200
2021-06-21T07:56:17.703677459Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:17.703714259Z Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2021-06-21T07:56:17.703720559Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:17.703725759Z Hosting environment: Development
2021-06-21T07:56:17.703730459Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:17.703735159Z Content root path: /app

2021-06-21T08:25:49.787Z INFO - Container logs from my-webapi_my-modules_0_01be8dfd = 2021-06-21T07:56:20.574323700Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
2021-06-21T07:56:20.575005009Z Storing keys in a directory '/root/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
2021-06-21T07:56:20.781515733Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
2021-06-21T07:56:20.781579234Z No XML encryptor configured. Key {0053fd50-0128-40a8-90be-7a468c5e50c1} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
2021-06-21T07:56:21.947839181Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:21.947893982Z Now listening on: http://[::]:5300
2021-06-21T07:56:21.979527015Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:21.979555215Z Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2021-06-21T07:56:21.980236224Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:21.980249425Z Hosting environment: Development
2021-06-21T07:56:21.986801914Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:21.986821414Z Content root path: /app

2021-06-21T08:25:51.929Z INFO - Container logs from my-webapi_my-systems_0_01be8dfd = 2021-06-21T07:56:23.554825952Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
2021-06-21T07:56:23.555495462Z Storing keys in a directory '/root/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
2021-06-21T07:56:23.790206570Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
2021-06-21T07:56:23.790240971Z No XML encryptor configured. Key {f6cc6acc-f66a-4f32-a900-e3a51407bdff} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
2021-06-21T07:56:24.406162791Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:24.406225392Z Now listening on: http://[::]:5400
2021-06-21T07:56:24.415819123Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:24.415838523Z Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2021-06-21T07:56:24.416663135Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:24.416675935Z Hosting environment: Development
2021-06-21T07:56:24.416680335Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:24.416684535Z Content root path: /app

2021-06-21T08:25:53.201Z INFO - Container logs from my-webapi_mywebgateway_0_01be8dfd = 2021-06-21T07:56:21.721002380Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
2021-06-21T07:56:21.721657189Z Storing keys in a directory '/root/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
2021-06-21T07:56:21.996907052Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
2021-06-21T07:56:21.996928453Z No XML encryptor configured. Key {849b5d69-efbd-42b2-84ad-16b3150026b2} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
2021-06-21T07:56:24.085502508Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:24.085526908Z Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5000
2021-06-21T07:56:24.085531808Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:24.085536008Z Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2021-06-21T07:56:24.085540008Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:24.085549708Z Hosting environment: Production
2021-06-21T07:56:24.085553408Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2021-06-21T07:56:24.085557308Z Content root path: /app

2021-06-21T08:25:55.352Z INFO - Stopping site my-webapi because it failed during startup.
```

This is the docker-compose file I used to build the container:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  my-identity:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/myidentity:latest
    container_name: my-identity
    ports:
      - "5100:5100"
    networks:
      - my-network
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: src/Web/Web.Apps/My.Identity.Web.App/Dockerfile      
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5100
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mysecretpassword
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/app/database/myRsaCert.pfx
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/dbs:/app/database
  
  my-sensors:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/mysensors:latest
    container_name: my-sensors
    ports:
      - "5200:5200"
    networks:
     - my-network
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: src/Web/Web.Apps/My.Sensors.Web.App/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5200
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/dbs:/app/database
  
  my-modules:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/mymodules:latest
    container_name: my-modules
    ports:
      - "5300:5300"
    networks:
      - my-network
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: src/Web/Web.Apps/My.Modules.Web.App/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5300
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/dbs:/app/database
  
  my-systems:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/mysystems:latest
    container_name: my-systems
    ports:
      - "5400:5400"
    networks:
      - my-network
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: src/Web/Web.Apps/My.Systems.Web.App/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5400
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/dbs:/app/database
      
  mywebgateway:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/mywebgateway:latest
    container_name: mywebgateway
    ports:
      - "80:5000"
    #mem_limit: 160m
    networks:
      - my-network
    links:
      - my-identity
      - my-modules
      - my-sensors
      - my-systems
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: src/Web/My.Web.Gateway/Dockerfile
networks:
  my-network:
   name: my-network
```

The following is the docker-compose file I used as the *configuration file* for the Azure App Service. I could not use the previous one, because it would throw the error `Linux Version is too long. It cannot be more than 4000 characters.` when trying to create the App Service resource.

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  my-identity:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/myidentity:latest
    container_name: my-identity
    ports:
      - "5100:5100"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5100
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mysecretpassword
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/app/database/myRsaCert.pfx
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/dbs:/app/database
  my-sensors:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/mysensors:latest
    container_name: my-sensors
    ports:
      - "5200:5200"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5200
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/dbs:/app/database
  my-modules:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/mymodules:latest
    container_name: my-modules
    ports:
      - "5300:5300"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5300
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/dbs:/app/database
  my-systems:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/mysystems:latest
    container_name: my-systems
    ports:
      - "5400:5400"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5400
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/dbs:/app/database
  mywebgateway:
    image: mycr.azurecr.io/mywebgateway:latest
    container_name: mywebgateway
    ports:
      - "80:5000"
    links:
      - my-identity
      - my-modules
      - my-sensors
      - my-systems
```

I placed the prepared databases and the myRsaCert.pfx in the shared storage of the App Service using FTP.

Does anyone have any idea why this webapi fails to start?

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not solve the issues with the Azure App Service, I moved my docker-compose application to an Azure virtual machine and it works fine.